# postgreSQL psql: ERROR: No such database: inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23

Tags: postgresql

When I restore database by this

`command:psql -h 10.0.0.88 -p 5432 -U zonst -d inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23 <  '/home/tonnn/inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23.bak'`

it shows this error

> psql: ERROR:  No such database: inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23

But i have created database `inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23`
and if i input `\l` in psql client, it will show database  `inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23`.

but i cannot connect to `inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23`, if i input `\c inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23`, it will show error

> ERROR:  No such database: inunion_old_fnc_2017_8_23

too. What is the wrong?

And it is the print of \l+
[print of \l+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTb0E.png)

Comment: Could you give us the actual print of \l+?

Comment: i have updated the question, the screenshot is under the question

Comment: That is weird. Sorry I cannot figure out why. Maybe you could try to drop the database and re-create it.

Comment: i already know why, it's because the posggreSQL server side has the pgbouncer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "Single database mode needs to be enabled" This worked for connecting to hosted timescale db's

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/configuring-database-connections.html#enable-single-connection-mode